# Unable to populate my javascript data to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I unable to connect my javascript file to html. I tried coding everything and now I am unable to see changes in HTML. I am here trying to calculate the tax rate of employees with their overtime worked with tax deduction .

Thanks in advance. Please help.

**My code for html is**

```
    <!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="employees.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="employees.css" />
    <title>Pay Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="content">
        <h1>
            Employee Payroll Entry Form
        </h1>
        <div id="payForm">
            <p>
                <label for="fullName">Full Name:</label><input type="text" autofocus id="fullName" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="hoursWorked">Hours Worked:</label><input type="text" id="hoursWorked" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="hourlyRate">Hourly Rate:</label><input type="text" id="hourlyRate" />
            </p>
            <footer>
                <button id="calculateButton" onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <h1>
            Employee Payroll Summary Report
        </h1>

        <table id = "employees">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Gross Pay</th>
                <th>Tax</th>
                <th>Net Pay</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>
```

and my **javascript is**

```
    var fname = document.getElementById("fullName");
    var hours = document.getElementById("hoursWorked");
    var rate = document.getElementById("hourlyRate");
    var table = document.getElementById("employees");
    var gross;
    var net;
    var tax;
    var overtime;

    function grosspay() {
if (hours > 0 && hours < 40) {
    gross = hours * rate;
} else if (hours < 40) {
    overtime = hours - 40;
    gross = (40 * rate) + (overtime * (rate * 1.5));
}
    }
    function taxPay() {
if (gross < 250) {
    tax = gross * 0.25;
} else if (gross >= 250 && gross < 500) {
    tax = gross * 0.30;
} else if (gross >= 500 && gross < 750) {
    tax = gross * 0.40;
} else if (gross > 750) {
    tax = gross * 0.50;
}
    }
    function netPay() {
net = gross - tax;
    }

    function calculate() {
if (hours > 0) 
{
    var row = table.insertRow();
    var fnamecell = row.insertCell(0);
    var grossPaycell = row.insertCell(1);
    var taxCell = row.insertCell(2);
    var netPayCell = row.insertCell(3);

    grosspay();
    taxPay();
    netPay(); 


    fnamecell.innerHTML = fname;
    grossPaycell.innerHTML = grosspay;
    taxCell.innerHTML = tax;
    netPayCell.innerHTML = net;       
}
    }
     function load() {
var calculateButton = document.getElementById("calculateButtom");
calculateButton.addEventListener("click", calculate);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using  a javascript debugger like firebug?

Answer (score 0):

you are get the elements like "hours" but not its value.

Please try the following calculate function and if still got problem please post the debugger output so that others can help you.

```
function calculate() {
    var hoursValue = hours.value;
    console.log("Hours are : " + hoursValue );

    if (hoursValue > 0) 
    {
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var fnamecell = row.insertCell(0);
        var grossPaycell = row.insertCell(1);
        var taxCell = row.insertCell(2);
        var netPayCell = row.insertCell(3);

        grosspay();
        taxPay();
        netPay(); 


        fnamecell.innerHTML = fname;
        grossPaycell.innerHTML = grosspay;
        taxCell.innerHTML = tax;
        netPayCell.innerHTML = net;       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are get the elements but not its value.

get the values of input fields like:

```
var hours = document.getElementById("hoursWorked").value;
var rate = document.getElementById("hourlyRate").value;
```

and also move script tag to the bottom of the page inside body tag.